# Android Espresso Testing with phone number (sms) authentication

Tags: android, authentication, android-espresso

I am trying to create and run Espresso UI tests for my android application.

The application uses phone number (sms) authentication. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

And every activity needs authenticated user info.
(So I can not test any activity without login.)

How can i get "Incoming SMS Verification Code" and authenticate automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a verification message is received on the user's device, Play services explicitly broadcasts to your app a `SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION` Intent, which contains the text of the message. Use a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive this verification message.

In the `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` handler, get the text of the verification message from the Intent's extras

For more infos click [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request#4_receive_verification_messages).